# How do I use browserify to convert node to the browser? nothing works for me?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

***Hi.***

I have this code:

```
import request from 'request';
import fs from 'fs'




const url = 'https://transfermarkt-api.vercel.app/players/28003/profile';
const headers = {
 'accept': 'application/json'
};




var myBody={}
request({
    url,
    headers
},

  (err, response, body) => {
   if (err) {

    console.error(err);

   } else {
    myBody = JSON.parse(body)
    
    console.log(myBody.name);
   }
   


fs.writeFileSync('data.json', JSON.stringify(myBody));
});
```

When I run node app.js in the terminal, i get this response:

```
PS C:\Users\Gili\Downloads\transfermarktProject> node app.js
Messi
```

I am trying to take this data and display it in the browser side,
after doing a little research i found out that browserify can convert the node log to the browser.

I have followed countless tutorials on how to use browserify but none of them work. i got a bunch of errors in the console when i tried them.

Here is an example of the errors i got when trying the geeksforgeeks tutorial:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://transfermarkt-api.vercel.app/players/28003/profile' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
bundle.js:38215     GET https://transfermarkt-api.vercel.app/players/28003/profile net::ERR_FAILED 200
ClientRequest._onFinish @ bundle.js:38215
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:38133
emit @ bundle.js:23445
finishMaybe @ bundle.js:14114
endWritable @ bundle.js:14129
Writable.end @ bundle.js:14070
ClientRequest.end @ bundle.js:38385
Request.end @ bundle.js:77255
end @ bundle.js:76311
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:76325
onNextTick @ bundle.js:39034
Item.run @ bundle.js:34461
drainQueue @ bundle.js:34431
setTimeout (async)
runTimeout @ bundle.js:34349
process.nextTick @ bundle.js:34451
exports.setImmediate @ bundle.js:39027
Request.init @ bundle.js:76270
Request @ bundle.js:75874
request @ bundle.js:74333
268.fs @ bundle.js:41085
o @ bundle.js:1
r @ bundle.js:1
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:1
bundle.js:41090 TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at ClientRequest._onFinish (bundle.js:38215:10)
    at module.exports.<anonymous> (bundle.js:38133:8)
    at module.exports.emit (bundle.js:23445:5)
    at finishMaybe (bundle.js:14114:14)
    at endWritable (bundle.js:14129:3)
    at Writable.end (bundle.js:14070:22)
    at ClientRequest.end (bundle.js:38385:32)
    at Request.end (bundle.js:77255:14)
    at end (bundle.js:76311:14)
    at bundle.js:76325:7
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:41090
self.callback @ bundle.js:75932
emit @ bundle.js:23445
Request.onRequestError @ bundle.js:76624
emit @ bundle.js:23445
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:38229
Promise.then (async)
ClientRequest._onFinish @ bundle.js:38222
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:38133
emit @ bundle.js:23445
finishMaybe @ bundle.js:14114
endWritable @ bundle.js:14129
Writable.end @ bundle.js:14070
ClientRequest.end @ bundle.js:38385
Request.end @ bundle.js:77255
end @ bundle.js:76311
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:76325
onNextTick @ bundle.js:39034
Item.run @ bundle.js:34461
drainQueue @ bundle.js:34431
setTimeout (async)
runTimeout @ bundle.js:34349
process.nextTick @ bundle.js:34451
exports.setImmediate @ bundle.js:39027
Request.init @ bundle.js:76270
Request @ bundle.js:75874
request @ bundle.js:74333
268.fs @ bundle.js:41085
o @ bundle.js:1
r @ bundle.js:1
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:1
bundle.js:41095 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _fs.default.writeFileSync is not a function
    at Request._callback (bundle.js:41095:18)
    at self.callback (bundle.js:75932:22)
    at Request.emit (bundle.js:23445:5)
    at Request.onRequestError (bundle.js:76624:8)
    at module.exports.emit (bundle.js:23445:5)
    at bundle.js:38229:10
```

Does anyone know how i can use browserify to display my log in the browser? Is browserify the right tool for this?

Comment: Browserify will convert code using modules "require" and exports into a bundle readable into a browser but it wont be able to translate code specifically written for a nodejs context (like using fs etc) into a browser context. You'll just have yo rewrite the code for this, no automation can figure out for you what to do if fs (for example) is not available.

Comment: ou need a server-side proxy to get around CORS, a well-beaten path around here with lots of suggestions.

Comment: @Peterrabbit how would i "rewrite" this code? can you elaborate please? thanks.

Comment: You have to recode your program because the browser context has nothing in common with node context. Browserify doesnt convert nodejs code into browser code, it just allows you to develop using require and exports module and transpile it into one bundle to load into the browser. In your code you use fs and other nodejs libs, those wont work in a browser so you have to rewrite your code and choose tools that will be availbale in a web browser... fs could be replaced by local storage etc for example...